# How to get a map of all data types from pymysql.cursor.description?

Tags: python, mysql, mysql-python, pymysql

For sql_select_query = 'select * from table', you can use `pymysql` python module to connect to MySql database and cursor.description to extract values.

```
def conn():
    myDb=pymysql.connect(server,user,password,database)
    return myDb

dbc = conn() #database connection
dbCursor = dbc.cursor() # cursor

# gathers all column field names and their type
field_names_and_type = [desc[:2] for desc in dbCursor.description]
```

Example output:

```
print(field_names_and_type)

[('ItemId', 1), ('ItemName', 3)]
```

type 1 is nvchar

type 3 is int

Question: how to i map these?
I've checked pymysql [docs](https://pymysql.readthedocs.io/) but could not find the mapping for cursor.description output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Pymysql` type codes are defined in [pymysql.constants.FIELD_TYPE](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL/blob/master/pymysql/constants/FIELD_TYPE.py)

```
DECIMAL = 0
TINY = 1
SHORT = 2
LONG = 3
FLOAT = 4
DOUBLE = 5
NULL = 6
TIMESTAMP = 7
LONGLONG = 8
INT24 = 9
DATE = 10
TIME = 11
DATETIME = 12
YEAR = 13
NEWDATE = 14
VARCHAR = 15
BIT = 16
JSON = 245
NEWDECIMAL = 246
ENUM = 247
SET = 248
TINY_BLOB = 249
MEDIUM_BLOB = 250
LONG_BLOB = 251
BLOB = 252
VAR_STRING = 253
STRING = 254
GEOMETRY = 255

CHAR = TINY
INTERVAL = ENUM
```

Comment: Worth mentioning that TINY = CHAR and DOUBLE = DECIMAL.